# Check Firebase for existing data before overwriting?

Tags: ios, swift, firebase

I have the following data in Firebase:

> - devices
>
>   - iphone5
>
>     - date_created: "1456183905"

I'm trying to determine if "**date_created**" exists, and if it doesn't then create it.

I read about snapshots, but is there an easier way to check Firebase to see if this data exists?  What I have now is using snapshots, but it is tied to an event handler.  Can't I just do a basic query to see if this entry exists or not?

Thanks.

Comment: You can actually handle this in your security rules, check out https://www.firebase.com/docs/security/api/rule/validate.html

Comment: Oh!  Security rules can do this?  Awesome, thanks, I'll use those.  Thanks, André.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can test if a value exists in your Swift code, by:

```
let ref = Firebase(url: "https://stackoverflow.firebaseio.com/35570687")
ref.observeSingleEventOfType(.Value, withBlock: { snapshot in
    if (!snapshot.exists()) {
        ref.setValue([".sv": "timestamp"])
    }
    else {
        print("already exist")
    }
})
```

But since this is only client-side, there is a chance that two clients will run the code at almost the exact time and both end up writing the timestamp. In the snippet above that wouldn't be a problem, but in real use-cases this sort of race condition might be unwanted.

As Andre commented, you can validate this in your security rules:

```
"date_created": {
  ".write": "!data.exists() || data.val() == newData.val()"
```

This validates that either this is the first time you write `date_created` (so the data won't exist yet) or otherwise that the value is unchanged.

Comment: Thanks guys, much appreciated!

Comment: Actually, just a note, it turns out that the security rule example in the answer needs to be ".validate" and not ".write".  At least in my code that is what made it worked.  It wasn't working and I couldn't figure it out until I changed that.  Still, I appreciate all the help!

Comment: Hmmm, I used `.write`, because `.validate` won't fire for a delete operation. If that's not a problem for you, then "yay". :-)

Comment: I couldn't get `.write` to fire during a write, is the thing.  Maybe I was doing something wrong?  I won't have to worry about deletes at this point - if I do I'll change the rule.  So far `.validate` works.